# Rails group_by with empty results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following models:

```
class Task
  belongs_to :task_category
end

class TaskCategory
  has_many :tasks
end
```

I want to group tasks by task category and this works for me:

```
Task.all.group_by(&:task_category)
# => 
{
  #<TaskCategory id: 1, name: "call", ... } =>[#<Task id: 1, ...>, #<Task id: 2, ...>], 
  #<TaskCategory id: 2, name: "event", ... } =>[#<Task id: 3, ...>, #<Task id: 4, ...>]
}
```

The problem is I want all task categories returned even if the task collection is empty. Therefore, something like this would work:

```
#<TaskCategory id: 3, name: "todo", ... } =>[]
```

In this case, the task category has no tasks, so the value is an empty array. Does the group_by support an option to allow this? If not, can this be done elegantly in a one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TaskCategory.all.includes(:task)` would work wouldn't it?  The data you get back would be in a slightly different format, but not significantly so.

Comment: Yes you are right, and the use of includes allows me to iterate over the collection without firing additional queries.

Comment: @Donato its simply eager_loading

Answer (score 0):

If you just do `TaskCategory.all`, you can get the tasks grouped by the category that you need. The format isn't exactly the same but still grouped the way you want it:

```
TaskCategory.all
# Assuming the first TaskCategory has no tasks
TaskCategory.all.first.tasks
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

A `TaskCategory` with no `tasks` would yield `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>` which is somewhat equivalent to `[]`.